# How to switch my latest stable Ubuntu installation to the development version?

Tags: upgrade, testing

I've installed ubuntu 20.04, however I'd like to install the development version (to use rolling rhino). Can I upgrade to the development version? or do I need to do a fresh install with the development image?

Comment: I would expect `do-release-upgrade -d` to bump you to *groovy*.  Have you tried?  (*sorry I did it back in April, which feels long ago now, and will bump again in October*).

Comment: If you don't already know the answer, you may not be prepared for Rolling Rhino yet. The development version is pre-release...it will become Ubuntu 20.10, to be released in October 2020. It means you are volunteering to be a tester. You will have the best experience if you have the skills to file effective bug reports, a handy knowledge of how  your commonly-used software stacks function so you can do basic troubleshooting, and a fair understanding of how deb and snap package tools work. Be equipped to handle critical bugs and possible data loss.

Comment: @guiverc thanks, this could be made into the answer.

Comment: @user535733 fair point. This isn't my main system and everything is backed up elsewhere, so this is a system I don't mind running in-development software.

Comment: @ideasman42 if you are prepared for the bumps in the road, then go for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do-release-upgrade` has a '-d' option.

From my release (currently *groovy*) `man do-release-upgrade` reports

> ```
>    -d, --devel-release
>           If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release
> ```

so assuming you're using the latest supported release (currently Ubuntu 20.04 LTS), you can

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

As @user535733 mentioned

> The development version is pre-release...it will become Ubuntu 20.10,
> to be released in October 2020. It means you are volunteering to be a
> tester. You will have the best experience if you have the skills to
> file effective bug reports, a handy knowledge of how your
> commonly-used software stacks function so you can do basic
> troubleshooting, and a fair understanding of how deb and snap package
> tools work.

Myself, this install was made late in the *artful* development cycle, and has been *release-upgraded* every six months a few days after each release since, and I've only had problems extremely rarely, however most of us have different hardware, different things we do on our systems, thus experiences may differ. My system is dual-boot, so if I have real problems, I can just dual boot and use my other system (*currently still Ubuntu 18.04 LTS*)